# How do I adjust my content views so that they are not obscured by the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When the keyboard slides up in my iPhone application, it obscures a large portion of the screen.  How do I adjust my views so that they are not hidden under the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find nice code for that [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).
Just go to the section called : **Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard**

You can use and adapt what the documentation said to move your view when the keyboard is visible.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I usually move up my whole UIView so you can see both keyboard and textfield

Comment: myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-100,320,480)
To make it smoother you can try to make it through an animation.