# UI controls are not visible

Tags: iphone

hello i have created ui progrmatically which consist of 7 textfields controls.Whenever i am clicking on textfield keyboard is popped up.but it hides the remaining textfield.So please help me so i can move the UI on click of textfield which are at the bottom

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564420/how-do-i-adjust-my-content-views-so-that-they-are-not-obscured-by-the-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

some of the link more useful for you...[view change](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)..